# Precision getting wrong in dart, how to fix that?

Tags: dart

My dart code:

```
 main()
    {
    print("sample data");
    print(700*0.002);
    print(7000*0.002);
    print(70*0.002);
    }
```

The output:

```
sample data
1.4000000000000001
14.0
0.14
```

Why the output is different in case of 700?
How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is floating-point aliasing due to their [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation and not unique to dart

Python:

```py
>>> 700*0.002
1.4000000000000001
```

Just display them with something float-aware and the precision will be right or move your math into an integer space